# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create an authentication signature for an API I am trying to consume in Python, what I am trying to is,

1) The signature is created by using a copy of the query string part of the URI, an example of which is shown below.

> ?customerId=johns Trucks&userName=BobH&timeStamp=2014-05-01T11:00:00Z

2) Ensure you encode your private key using UTF8 encoding.  Once encoded you can create your signature by using your private key

3) Convert the signature created from step 2 into base64.

4) If we use a private key of fakekey, the signature for the above URI string will look like this after it has been calculated with HMAC-SHA1 and then converted to base64

> PeKNVo1BAiuZyHxIdMisidG92bg=

5) The signature is now ready to be added to the Http authentication header for the request.

The above is taken from straight from the documentation and below is my attempt,

```
private_key = bytes("auth", encoding='utf-8');
public_key = bytes("200000", encoding='utf-8');
customer_id = "HFH";
username = "API";

date_utc = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
message = bytes('?customerId=HFH&userName=API&timeStamp=' + date_utc, encoding='utf-8')

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(private_key, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest())
encoded_sig = base64.b64encode(signature)

url = 'https://xxx.xxxxxxx.net/api/FleetVehicles?customerId=HFH&userName=API&timeStamp=' + date_utc;

data = requests.get(url, headers={'authorization:' + public_key + ":" + encoded_sig});
```

My code is resulting in the following error,

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

The error is coming from the final line of my code example.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your code is python 3.

Starting with Python 3, strings are now represented either as *unicode* strings or as *binary* data as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

> Python 3.0 uses the concepts of text and (binary) data instead of
>   Unicode strings and 8-bit strings. All text is Unicode; however
>   encoded Unicode is represented as binary data. The type used to hold
>   text is str, the type used to hold data is bytes. The biggest
>   difference with the 2.x situation is that any attempt to mix text and
>   data in Python 3.0 raises TypeError, whereas if you were to mix
>   Unicode and 8-bit strings in Python 2.x, it would work if the 8-bit
>   string happened to contain only 7-bit (ASCII) bytes, but you would get
>   UnicodeDecodeError if it contained non-ASCII values.

What you want here is either:

```
headers={b'authorization:' + public_key + b":" + encoded_sig})
```

(Note the `b` before the *static* strings)

or:

```
headers={'authorization:' + public_key.decode('utf-8') + ":" + encoded_sig.decode('utf-8')})
```

(Note the `.decode()` to convert your *bytes* as *str*)